# Do I need a voltage converter for my Surface tablet in Rome?

Tags: power, rome, toronto

I have a Surface Pro with charger that comes with box.

I checked Rome is using 220v and Canada is using 120v and is using some weird power plug like 3 holes in a line.

But as I remember all laptop charger is universal, so I guess I don't need a voltage converter?

And I wonder if hotels normally will have some power plug or converter for travellers?

Or do I have to buy one in Toronto Canada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But as I remember all laptop charger is universal, so I guess I don't need a voltage converter?

It should be printed on the charger - if it says something like "100-230V", you're fine. Usually this is the case for stuff that people are likely to travel with, such as laptops.

> And I wonder does those hotel normally will have some power plug or converter that for traveller?

Hotels sometimes have sockets that admit multiple different plugs. If so, the US/Canadian plug will always be included. But such sockets are not always present, and often only in the bathroom, which is not a good place for a computer.

> Or I have to buy one in Toronto Canada?

I would recommend this to be on the safe side. Plug adapters are cheap, shouldn't cost more than $5